# Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating System Error Code 5

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert an image into SQL Server using this SQL query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Employees(ImageColumn) 
   SELECT BulkColumn 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\employee.jpg', Single_Blob) AS img
```

but I'm getting this message:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\employee.jpg" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.).

Comment: Is your SQL Server running on your own machine? Or is it remote? A *remote* SQL Server (running on some other machine - not your own PC) will **NOT** be able to access the `C:\` drive on your local machine - and that's a *good* thing! If you're using a remote SQL Server, you must first copy the image file to **that server's harddisk** so you can insert it from there

Answer (score 1):

For whichever context you are running this SQL statement (e.g., in SSMS), try opening the [application as an admin](http://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-run-programs-as-administrator-in-windows-10-3632744).

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in to SSMS under the sa account and try that. I have a lot of permissions issues when I'm logged in as myself, even if I'm logged in with admin privileges.